# Is it slower to access std::map elements with at() than operator[]?

Tags: c++, stdmap

When I want get certain element from a `std::map`, as far as I know `at()` will do a bounds check. Does that mean it's slower than `[]`?

Comment: No, it is not slower. The only difference is, it does not create new element but throws an exception if an element does not exits.

Comment: @ S.M.  Thanks,no wonder I google so many times,and none of those reference say that ".at" is more slow

Comment: For a lot of containers with `[]` support it is slower because of the bounds check, but `map` has very different behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `std::map::at` and `std::map::operator[]` check for the presence of a key. The former throws an exception when not found, the latter creates a default value.

Their complexity is mandatory to be `log(n)` (look-up).
Performance by itself is not mandatory to be identical, but should be similar in practice.

So choose the one to use from their behavior (after the look-up). Similar alternatives might be `map::find` or in some cases `map::insert`/`insert_or_assign`/`emplace`.